# Why hidden attribute inside a modal can't be modified?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've encountered a problem on changing the hidden attribute inside a modal I can't change the value of it.

I've tried this code

```
function SignUp() {

        $("#regModal").modal('show');
        $('#message1').attr('hidden', true);
        $('#message2').attr('hidden', true);

    }
```

And this is the div inside the modal that I want to modify

```
<div class="modal" id="regModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           !-- Modal Header -->
           <div class="modal-header">
               <div id="message1" hidden="false">
                   <div class="alert alert-success">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                       <strong>
                        Success Message!<br />
                        Sent an email to your email address with confirmation <br />
                        link!  please check your inbox <br />
                      </strong>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is working at first click but after i used this code the div always show even if i close the modal and open it again.

```
$('#message1').attr('hidden',false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you want to hide or show the div :

Add inline style in the div element with id : `message1`

```
<div class="modal" id="regModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           !-- Modal Header -->
           <div class="modal-header">
               <div id="message1" style="display:block;">
                   <div class="alert alert-success">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                       <strong>
                        Success Message!<br />
                        Sent an email to your email address with confirmation <br />
                        link!  please check your inbox <br />
                      </strong>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery :

```
 $("#message1").attr('style','display: none'); // to hide the div
```

OR If you don't want to add inline style, you can simply do the following :

```
$('#message1').css('display', 'none'); // To hide the div
```

and

```
$('#message1').css('display', 'block'); // To show the div
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly for me :) I also like the shorter method without the inline style. :)

Comment: Anytime :) @ikey

Answer (score 0):

how to hide,
$("#message1").hide();

how to show,
$("#message1").show();

Comment: I've also tried this but this also doesn't work for me.